# ¿Como posicionar un JLabel detrás de otras JLabel en java?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación la cual consta de un `JPanel` al cual le voy agregando diferentes tipos de componentes ya sea `JLabel`, `JButton`.

Lo que quiero saber es si existe alguna forma de llevarlas hacia atrás o hacia delante, mover hacia el frente o mover hacia atras, o poner una `JLabel` detras de todos los componentes que existan.

Comment: Que layout utilizas? abosoluteLayout puede que te funcione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente logre posicionar las `JLabel` una encima de otra cambiando el `JPane` por un `JLayeredPane` y utilizando el metodo:

`nombreJlayered.add(nombreDeEtiqueta, new Integer(1));`